# What were the powers of Alvin as a seventh son of a seventh son?

Tags: orson-scott-card, alvin-maker

It has been quite awhile since I've read those books, and I may not have even completed them. Lots of people seem to have a "knack" for special abilities in the series, but Alvin (and Calvin) as seventh sons of a seventh son, either have a lot of "knacks" or have something else.

What is the extent (or the limitiations) of Alvin's powers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They were Makers, and as far as I understood it they were able to make come about just about whatever they could conceive of in their mind. They did have to actually be able to "see" what they were making in their mind and how it was made, not just say "I'd like a billion dollars" and there it is. They would have had to have all the core materials and understand how the materials in the bills were woven and the ink created and how it was applied to the paper-cotton weave in order to make each one of them. Note that understanding the make up of a bill does not require understanding how to make it, but simply requires knowing what it is made of and how it is arranged.

That is the basics of the Maker. With proper will and discipline, however, it was shown that it was possible for a Maker to alter the atomic structure of an object, thus completely changing one thing into another. Alvin was also a little more than that thanks to his time with the Native Americans, granting him some of their special abilities (the ability to hear the Green Song for example).

Comment: Alvin is a particularly strong maker; I would go so far as to rank him as a demigod. He was able to change the DNA of every cell in a friend's body enough to throw off a witchfinder's knack. That's far more complicated than making things at the macro level, like money, and he was able to "see" magically enough to do this in a very short time without prior knowledge of DNA, molecular chemistry, etc. Words for those things didn't even exist in that period of history in the real world. Perhaps Card jumped the shark a little there.

Comment: @ohmi Well, the reasoning in the book is that Alvin was able to "see" how things in himself looked at that level (with his "bug") and he just changed a small part of his friend to match himself. The core materials were there (proteins, etc) and Alvin had an understanding of how it all went together in himself and Made it the same in his friend. It was even remarked that in doing so his friend gain a bit of the Maker ability and behaved a little like Alvin as well afterwards.

Comment: You are right, but that seems to imply that once he figured that out he could change anyone's DNA (and expressed, working proteins/exons/RNA) in any way he could abstractly visualize. IIRC, he was quite uncomfortable afterwards about the consequences and resolved to never do it again? Still, full-on demigod compared to every other person in the series.

Comment: I'd say Alvin and Calvin were equal power-wise, as far as being Makers. Calvin just lacked the discipline to understand his power as intimately and painted with a **much** broader brush.

Comment: He also lacked all of the other knacks (witch-hunters and wood-shapers for example) and he did not have other abilities, like the ability to use Voodoo or to see the soul threads like the weavers.